# How would you name this function

Tags: functions, summation

We have the following function.  I'm trying to give this a functional name.  Specifically what I'm looking for is a name to give $U_o$.

$U_o = \frac{(\Sigma (U_i * A_i))}{A}$ for $i = 1, n$

$U$ is a measure of resistivity ($U$-Value) of a window
$A$ is the area of the window.

I understand the math.  What I don't understand is what name to give it.  "Total $U$-Value" and "Aggregate $U$-Value" don't feel correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This looks like a weighted average

Comment: In layman's terms what is $U_o$?

Comment: Arthur. I would call it Arthur. RIP George Harrison. (SCNR)